# search autocomplete ajax in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am using ajax for live searching, but the problem is that It is shown only one result

when I am using .html() but when I am using append() it works but every word i write it to duplicate the results,

here is my code:

in controller,

```
   $patient = Patient::select('id', 'avatar')
        ->where('phone_number', 'like', '%' . $search_query . '%')
        ->orWhere('first_name', 'like', '%' . $search_query . '%')
        ->limit(15)
        ->get();
        return $patient;
```

ajax code in blade

```
    $("#search-eng").keyup(function() {
        let search_query = $(this).val();
        if (search_query != "") {
            $.ajax({
                url: '{{ url('/appointment/calander_patient_search') }}/' +
                    search_query,
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                    $("#search-eng-show-list").show();

                    if (data !== "") {

                        $.each(data, function(key, value) {

                            $('#search-eng-show-list').html(

                                '<a data-id="' + value.id + '"' value.second_name + '</a>');
                        });
                    }
                    if (data == "") {
                        $('#search-eng-show-list').html(
                            '<a><i "></i>No Record</a>'
                        );
                    }
                },
            });
        } else {
            $("#search-eng-show-list").empty();
            $("#search-eng-show-list").hide();;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you set your content in your loop statement, so it will only take the last content.

You can use some buffer variable :

```
if (data !== "") {
   var html = '';

   $.each(data, function(key, value) {
       html += '<a data-id="' + value.id + '"' value.second_name + '</a>');
   }

   $('#search-eng-show-list').html(html);

   // ....
```

Comment: thank you so much, it works well. sorry for asking but what is better, using the search engine as above or sending all results by controller including HTML, and just pass them to div?

Comment: Still better to send JSON, then your front can manipulate them easily. It's better to use some JS frameworks (VueJS, React...), they have data binding which allow you to manipulate more easily your JSON data. jQuery is a little outdated.

Comment: thank you for your help i would learn them soon.